# Get other data from object using Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I have two collections of objects, A and B.  A is from a CSV file and B is from `Get-ADUser`.  Both A and B have a field named "Username".  What I want to be able to do is check if B contains A, and if so, copy the description from B into A.  Something like this:

```
$A.'Description' = $B | ? {$A.Username -eq $B.Username; $B.Description}
```

I feel like there is a way to do this without iterating across another loop (I'm already looping through each obj in A).

Comment: `foreach ($AUser in $A) { $AUser.Description = ($B | Where {$_.Username -eq $AUser.UserName}).Description }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) mapping the usernames from `$B` to the respective descriptions:

```
$ht = @{}
$B | ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Username] = $_.Description }
```

Then iterate over the elements of `$A` and update those descriptions if `$ht` contains a matching key:

```
$A | Where-Object {
    $ht.ContainsKey($_.Username)
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Description = $ht[$_.Username]
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what you consider downvote-worthy about my answer?